# Main scss file not updating all imported files with script

Tags: css, sass

This is the code I have in my package.json to look for any changes in sass folder:

```
"scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w='sass/'"
  },
```

And this is what my main.scss file looks like:

```
@import "abstracts/functions";
@import "abstracts/mixins";
@import "abstracts/variables";

@import "base/animations";
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/utilities";
@import "base/base";

@import "components/button";
@import "components/cards";
@import "components/story";
@import "components/composition";
@import "components/feature-box";

@import "layout/header";
@import "layout/grid";

@import "pages/home";
```

I also have node live-server thing running so every time I make any changes in
my HTML/CSS it updates automatically, but it doesn't update whenever I change anything inside components folder. If I want my HTML/CSS to get updated I have to first save components file and then re-save anything under base, abstracts, layouts or pages folder. Any idea why is it doing that? My sass folder looks like that in my project https://gyazo.com/3c0c9c8d190cda2fe49ec00b333aad8a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your watch function. I guess you are using something like `watch(sass/main.scss)`. Along with it, try adding this `watch(sass/*/*.scss)`. This will make it look for changes in all the files. Hope it helps.

Comment: Always here to help :))